# What is the best way to clear the console in a window with a running rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, buffer, iterm2

I have iTerm2 and I was able to right click on the running server window and select "Clear Buffer" - but I'm not sure this is the right solution. I want to keep my history, I just don't want to have to scroll through ALLLLL of the output logged with the server. I apologize if this is unclear. Below is a gif with type of output that I want to be able to clear, periodically: [example of output that i want to clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmLuE.gif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cmd-K will clear the buffer & scrollback for you